# Order by one column and then by another

Tags: mysql

This is my table:

```
ID UserID Client Time(timestamp)

1  25     Acer   2017-09-13 09:09:13
2  21     Lenovo 2017-09-13 12:09:32
3  20     HP     2017-09-13 14:04:26
4  21     Dell   2017-09-13 17:04:23
5  25     Apple  2017-09-13 17:09:46
.
.
.
```

I want the result to be ordered by timestamp first, fetching the first 5 records, and then ordering by user id like this

```
ID UserID Client Time(timestamp)
5  25     Apple  2017-09-13 17:09:46
1  25     Acer   2017-09-13 09:09:13
4  21     Dell   2017-09-13 17:04:23
2  21     Lenovo 2017-09-13 12:09:32
3  20     HP     2017-09-13 14:04:26
```

i tried this query

```
select * from table order by time Desc, UserID LIMIT 5;
```

but it doesn't seem to work, instead i get this as the result

```
ID UserID Client Time(timestamp)
5  25     Apple  2017-09-13 17:09:46
4  21     Dell   2017-09-13 17:04:23
3  20     HP     2017-09-13 14:04:26
2  21     Lenovo 2017-09-13 12:09:32
1  25     Acer   2017-09-13 09:09:13
```

I am not sure where i am going wrong.

Comment: sort by UserId and then by time. select * from table order by UserID, time Desc;

Comment: that is not an option because i am taking the first 5 values from table based on timestamp

Comment: So, are you saying you will fetch 5 rows first then you will sort them or first sort them and then get first 5 rows ? Both are different because.

Comment: Yes, fetch 5 rows first based on time stamp DESC and then order them by userID

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to do this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM table
    ORDER BY time DESC
    LIMIT 5
) AS firstusers
ORDER BY UserID
```

Comment: This works. But the query takes a while to run since i have a big database, is there any way to make it faster ?

Comment: You can try it like this select * from table where UserId in (select userId from table order by time desc limit 5) order by UserId.

Comment: @IuriiDrozdov your suggested query where you are telling to use `IN` will take longer time

Answer (score 5):

It should be `order by  UserID DESC, time Desc` instead:

```
select * 
from table1 order by  UserID DESC, time Desc;
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3562cd/2)

This will give you the same order you are looking for:

```
| ID | UserID | Client |                 Time |
|----|--------|--------|----------------------|
|  5 |     25 |  Apple | 2017-09-13T17:09:46Z |
|  1 |     25 |   Acer | 2017-09-13T09:09:13Z |
|  4 |     21 |   Dell | 2017-09-13T17:04:23Z |
|  2 |     21 | Lenovo | 2017-09-13T12:09:32Z |
|  3 |     20 |     HP | 2017-09-13T14:04:26Z |
```

Comment: i have more values in the table, i am taking the first 5 rows based on timestamp and then have to order by user id

Comment: @HarshaJasti So what is the issue? I don't understand, this will give you the same exact results you are looking for, please see the sql fiddle demo. Did you tried the query? Whats wrong with it??

Comment: my table has more values, for example userID=30 with time=2017-09-11T17:09:46 .. when we run the query, this row will show up because we ordered by user id first .. but the timestamp is older

Comment: so then change it to order by  time Desc, UserID DESC; But the picture in your question shows that you want it ordered first by  the userID

Answer (score 0):

OK. You need to fetch the first 5 records ordered by timestamp, and reorder them by userID. Here is the code:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT* FROM 
    table1 
    ORDER BY time DESC 
    LIMIT 5) firstfive 
ORDER BY UserID DESC
```

Comment: i have more values in the table, i am taking the first 5 rows based on timestamp ..

Comment: If you look at your data, the timestamp of record of ID 1 (Acer) is earlier than record of ID 4 (Dell). If you want to order by timestamp first, record 4 should come earlier than record 1.

Answer (score 0):

You need in-line view, where first get the 5 rows order by `time` and then `UserID`

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM table
    ORDER BY time DESC
    LIMIT 5
)
ORDER BY UserID DESC
```

So, above query has nested `select` which will execute first and get you 5 rows ordered descending by `time`. Then, we will use this resultset to outer query and order the row by UserID

Comment: this threw me an error because AS wasn't used in the query. but it was almost correct. thanks

Comment: @HarshaJasti `AS` is not required